# add alpha legend to ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks something like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
  y = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 1, sd = 1),
  color = sample(
    x = c('red', 'blue'), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(.5,.5)
  ),
  alpha = runif(n = 100, min = 0.1, max = 1)
)
```

I want to generate a scatter plot, and I want the only legend on the graph to be `alpha`, a continuous variable that can take values between 0.1 and 1.

This is what I have right now:

```
DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = x, y = y, color = color, size = 2, alpha = alpha
  )) +
  geom_point(show_guide = TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = color, alpha = alpha),size = 2) +
    geom_point() + 
    guides(color = "none") +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: Almost, the legend is taking 3 values instead of a continuous. Is that fixable?

Comment: @Ignacio I don't believe you can do a "colorbar" guide for alpha at the moment.

Comment: @Ignacio I may see a way to make some small changes that would allow a color bar for alpha scales. If I have some time later I'll try to put together a pull request and we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get `alpha` as a continuous scale, but legends for `color` and `size` can be removed by setting their guides to `FALSE`.

```
DF %>%
    ggplot(aes(
        x = x, y = y, color = color, size = 2, alpha = alpha
    )) +
    geom_point(show_guide = TRUE) + theme_bw() + 
scale_size(guide = FALSE) + 
scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```